# Can a contract control another address?

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, addresses

Say I have control of addresses A and B, and I am writing contract C. When I deploy C on the blockchain, it will have it's own address, that can send and receive ether. But I want to have a method on C which, when called, sends ether from address A to address B, *not* to or from C.

Of course I could do this by storing the private key for A in C, but then anyone could look at C, copy the key out, and use it themselves. I want to allow *only* C to send ether from A, not anyone else.

Is there any way to allow a contract to control another address, without making the key for that address publicly accessible?

Answer (score 3):

If A is a contract, then yes. If it is not, your reasoning is correct in that C in this situation would need the private key for A and that will be accessible to anyone who runs an Ethereum client or can read directly form the Ethereum blockchain.

If A is a contract, you can make a check in A such that only C is allowed to initiate a transfer of ether from A to B.

It could look like this in A:

```
if (msg.sender != "0xb7cB1C96dB6B22b0D3d9536E0108d062BD488F74"){
    return false;
}
/// Code to transfer ether
```

You can do this by simply hard coding C's address into the contract A and then compare C's address with `msg.sender` which returns the caller's address.

Since Ethereum addresses are deterministic, based upon the creator address and its nonce, you can even hard code and deploy A before you have deployed C.

Comment: This question has been voted down. It would be nice if the downvoters could leave a comment as to why they consider the answer bad.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this unless A is a smart contract.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. Here are the steps.

1. Create a smart contract `A` which allows only `C` to withdraw ether and send to any address.
2. Deploy an instance of `A` from inside of `C`. This will make `C` as the `msg.sender` for `A`.
3. This will create an address for `A` and there will be no private key available to access `A`.
4. The only one who can withdraw ethers from `A` would be contract `C`.